# How to convert float raster to vector with python GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, vectorization

I have float raster and now I want to convert it to vector. How is it possible with the Python GDAL library?

I have tried with `gdal_polygonize.py` of GDAL utilities on the command line and it worked excellently. But this utility is based on `GDALPolygonize()` of C++ library and I want to C++ method `GDALFPolygonize()` to be used instead, which manipulates float raster data as far as I know.

Answer (score 9):

Try using [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio), which uses [GDALFPolygonize](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/0a9debe3f43e9a4a66e2d389627252362acaa308/rasterio/_features.pyx#L114-115) on float arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from affine import Affine
from shapely.geometry import shape

# triangular array    
ar = np.tri(5, dtype='f')
print(ar)

for shp, val in rasterio.features.shapes(ar, transform=Affine(1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 5)):
    print('%s: %s' % (val, shape(shp)))
```

shows:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
1.0: POLYGON ((0 0, 0 5, 5 5, 5 4, 4 4, 4 3, 3 3, 3 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
0.0: POLYGON ((1 0, 1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 3 2, 3 3, 4 3, 4 4, 5 4, 5 0, 1 0))
```

Or visualised with blue for `1.0` and red for `0.0`:

[image: from JTS]

Answer (score 8):

You can't use `GDALFPolygonize` with the GDAL python bindings without modifying the source code and recompiling as it isn't exposed in the GDAL [swig interface](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/tags/2.0.2/gdal/swig/include/Operations.i).

Note: as at Feb 2016, `GDALFPolygonize` IS exposed in the GDAL SVN [trunk source](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/include/Operations.i), but is not in either of the latest releases (1.11.4/2.0.2).

To polygonize your raster,  you will need to convert from float to integer. If you want to retain some decimal places multiply your raster by 10^N where N is the number of decimal places you want to retain. For example, to keep 3 decimal places multiply by 10^3 = 1000.

```bsh
# Multiply raster values by 1000
gdal_calc.py -A raster.tif --outfile=raster1000.tif --calc="A*1000"

# Convert to vector
gdal_polygonize.py raster1000.tif vector1000.shp
```

If you want to convert your polygon attributes back to float then just divide by the same value.

```bsh
# Divide vector values by 1000
ogr2ogr vector.shp vector1000.shp -sql "select (cast(DN as float) * 0.001) as DN FROM vector1000"
```

Note there is no point converting floating point rasters which represent continuous surfaces to polygons as you will get pretty much 1 polygon per pixel which is very inefficient. Almost any analysis you can think of with such data is much more efficient if you leave the data in raster format.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but commenting if anyone finds this useful.
Let's say you have a float raster (raster_path) and you want to convert it to shapefile. You can use gdal FPolygonize within python as:

```
source_raster = gdal.Open(raster_path)      
band = gdal.Open(raster_path).GetRasterBand(1)
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')        
out_data = driver.CreateDataSource(shapefile_path)
# getting projection from source raster
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(source_raster.GetProjectionRef())
# create layer with projection
out_layer = out_data.CreateLayer(raster_path.split('.')[0], srs)        
new_field = ogr.FieldDefn('field_name', ogr.OFTReal)
out_layer.CreateField(new_field)        
gdal.FPolygonize(band, band, out_layer, 0, [], callback=None)        
out_data.Destroy()
source_raster = None
```