# gdal_polygonize floating values

Tags: qgis, gdal, polygonize, floating-point

gdal_polygonize converts whatever rasters values into vector integers as it is based on the GDALPolygonize() function (http://gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#a3f522a9035d3512b5d414fb4752671b1).

It is suggested that the GDALFPolygonize() function (http://gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#a7a789015334d677afcbef67e5a6b4a7c) should be employed in case floating points are to be transferred.

However, it is absolutely obscure to me how to implement or call such function instead of the standard one. No clue is available anywhere.

I'm calling gdal using both OSGeo4W shell as well as QGIS2.6 python interface (I'm on Windows 7 and 8.1).

Comment: The arguments are the same. So if you can use one, you should be able to use the other. Can you edit your question to explain what your question is?

Comment: GDALFPolygonize is not available in the Python bindings - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/128139/2856