# Grid-type shapefile from raster GeoTIFF

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, contour, gdal-contour

I need to produce a shapefile from a raster. I need to be able to specify either an interval, or manually define the intervals. The input file is a GeoTIFF. I would like to use GDAL and/or Python.

Example raster:

[image]

I tried using gdal_contour, which at first glance would have been perfect. However, I want the result to have the same "pixel" definition - that is, the "contours" should maintain the block appearance of the pixels at their extents. For this reason, I can't use gdal_contour, as the results look like this:

[image]

Is there another way to do this? My output should be a shapefile that looks like a grid, with only pixels in the same interval connected to each other.

Comment: You (may) have two questions here. The first is about reclassifying your raster (specification of intervals) for which you can see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116473/ Contour lines is an interpolation of the point values, not a direct vectorization. For that you can see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128139/ which discusses why it doesn't make sense to directly vectorize a float. However if that's *really* what you want to do, it can be done. Are you wanting lines or polygons for the vector geometry?

Comment: rasterToContours in the R package raster returns cell edges in a SpatialLinesDataFrame.

Comment: Hey @ChrisW - thanks for the response. My wording probably wasn't great. I want to have the option to specify intervals for the "contours" in my output. So, for instance, 10-30 should be a contour, 31-40 should be one, etc. gdal_contour can do this with the -fl argument. Just want to retain that functionality.

Anyway, the more important part: yes, I do want to directly polygonize the raster. It's not really an elevation, it represents a specific set of data that must go into the final system in this format. I'll take a look at your second link, looks like it might work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating contours is an interpolation, which is why your output looks like it does.

You need to reclassify using gdal_calc:
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html

But there is some good information here relating to reclassifying with either gdal or python:
[Reclassify rasters using GDAL and Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116473/reclassify-rasters-using-gdal-and-python)

And then convert to vector using gdal_polygonize:
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html