# File location of GDAL scripts

Tags: python, gdal

I am wondering where I can find the Python scripts of GDAL in Windows. I have installed GDAL with Conda and I have QGIS installed. I am looking for example for GDALFPolygonize.py
and polygonize.py as mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128139/how-to-convert-float-raster-to-vector-with-python-gdal) and [here](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html).

> *If you haven’t before, notice that some of the gdal utilties are actually Python scripts. Go find them on your computer, read the source code and mine them for API tricks. It turns out the gdal_polygonize utility just wraps a call to GDALFPolygonize so writing your own hacky polygonize Python script is pretty easy.*

Answer (score 6):

You can find the location of any module by checking the `__file__` attribute.

```
from osgeo import gdal
print(gdal.__file__)
```

Alternatively, you can also search for files in the [GDAL repository](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/69cd93cdb1af959383529a84ab154b56ab9b49d5). For example searching `repo:OSGeo/gdal polygonize.py` gives [these](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AOSGeo%2Fgdal%20polygonize.py&type=code) results (you need to be logged in) and you can find `polygonize.py` [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/69cd93cdb1af959383529a84ab154b56ab9b49d5/autotest/alg/polygonize.py#L4).

Comment: I did not manage to install osgeo or gdal in Pycharm, I might look into that later. But when I search for GDALFPolygonize in the repository, I find it used one time in polygonize() and one time in alg_h(), but I cannot find a script itself. Maybe it is not actually used anymore? Because the documentation I mentioned is actually from 2013...